# Oracle: How to find date of last Friday of the month

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any way, we can write a query in sql or pl/sql to find date of last friday of current month ?
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Could "Yes" be a good answer? Please do some search, try some code, show some effort and then, if you have a specific issue with your code, feel free to post a question here. Also, "a query in PLSQL" does not make much sense. Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `LAST_DAY( SYSDATE )` to get the last day of the month. If you subtract 7 days from that then you can use the `NEXT_DAY()` function to find the last Friday of the month:

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(
         LAST_DAY( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY,
         'FRIDAY'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Wrap it in `TRUNC()` if you want to truncate the date to midnight of that day.