# Oracle: Last Friday of the previous month

Tags: oracle

```
    SELECT 
      TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)-7, 'FRIDAY'),
                       ' DD MONTH, YYYY') "LAST_FRIDAY"
    FROM DUAL;
```

this will give me current month last Friday . I need a previous month last Friday.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406289/oracle-how-to-find-date-of-last-friday-of-the-month

Answer (score 2):

You are about to close, just you need to use the ADD_MONTH as below:

## 1. Compare to Today.

```
  SELECT 
      TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(add_months(SYSDATE,-1))-7, 'FRIDAY'),
                       ' DD MONTH, YYYY') "LAST_FRIDAY"
    FROM DUAL;
```

## 2. To get static last day

```
select dt
from(
SELECT to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)),'DD MONTH, YYYY') dt,
        to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1))-level,'DAY') dy
  FROM DUAL
  connect by rownum <= 7
) where trim(dy) = 'FRIDAY'
```

Comment: You don't need `TO_CHAR` - just return the value as a `DATE` data type.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but in question he/she used to_char to specified the output format thatswhy.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the query below.

My logic to that is:

1-Get the last day of previous month

2-Get the day of week from date of item 1

3-Some logic with "case" to get wish date

```
select case
         when WLD = 7 then LD-1 -- if Saturday, get previous day
         when WLD = 6 then LD   -- if Friday, then ok
         when WLD = 5 then LD-6 -- if Thursday, get 6 days ago
         when WLD = 4 then LD-5 -- if Wednesday, get 5 days ago
         when WLD = 3 then LD-4 -- if Tuesday, get 4 days ago
         when WLD = 2 then LD-3 -- if Monday, get 3 days ago
         when WLD = 1 then LD-2 -- if Sunday, get 2 days ago
       end as LAST_FRIDAY_LAST_MONTH -- HERE IS THE LAST FRIDAY OF MONTH
  from (          
        select last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate),-1))               as LD   -- last day of previous month
             , to_char(last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate),-1)),'D')  as WLD  -- week day of last day of previous month
          from dual
       )
```

Comment: `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='DENMARK';` and your query gives the wrong day (or any `NLS_TERRITORY` where Sunday is not the first day of the week).